# Linux Centos webserver Softlink (Symbolic Link) Issue

Tags: linux, recursion, symlink

To create a symbolic link in Linux webserver , at the shell prompt, i am using the
following command:

```
# ln -s {target-filename} {symbolic-filename}
```

For example to create softlink for

```
/viewer/PENG07/index.php
```

as

```
/home/name1/public_html/viewer/index.php
```

i enter the following command:

```
# ln -s /viewer/PENG07/index.php /home/name1/public_html/viewer/
```

Now the issue is it only loads index.php and misses the supporting sub folders and all next level folders and directories

what i want was to softlink (symbolic link)

```
/viewer
```

instead of

```
/viewer/index.php
```

to

```
/home/name1/public_html/viewer/
```

it should be recursive all folders and files ..

kindly help me please ...

Answer (score 0):

If `index.php` resides in `/viewer/PENG07`, you presumably mean to link `/viewer/PENG07` rather than just `/viewer`.

```
ln -s /viewer/PENG07 /home/name1/public_html/viewer
```

- Note: There must not be a `/` at the end.